# Packetriot server session dropping

Tags: localhost, tunneling

I am locally hosting my website from my pc but for the few days my localhost keeps dropping connection from the packetriot server with in few minutes and try attempt and connect again. how to increase the packetriot server session?

```
Tunnel session has expired on server, tearing down tunnel...



Tunnel connection was severed Mar 11, 2024 @ 23:01, reconnecting (attempt #10) in 30 seconds...      
Connected to asia-south-36774.packetriot.net...

Running HTTP services:
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+| Domain                      | Destination   | HTTP   | TLS   | Secure   | Protect   | Site Root   |+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+| xxxxxxxxxxxxx   | localhost     | 80     | 0     | true     |           | --          |+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Certificates from LetsEncrypt:
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Certificate Domain          | Status      | Expiration         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| xxxxxxxxxxx   | Available   | Jun 3 04:08 2024   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```